# Портлеты у себя на сайте

Tags: jsf, java

Если кто нибудь вкурсе то объясните мне. Могу ли я на своем сайте работающим под Tomcat или GlasFish где JSF, встроить портлеты или это должен быть обязательно какой нибудь LifeRay или IBM решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете. Для Tomcat есть Pluto. http://portals.apache.org/pluto/